# How do I pass data from adapter to mainactivity when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I Uploaded some data to sqlite and I want to delete each data from the recyclerview by pressing a button. so how can I achieve this? I want to get the id from recyclerview to the mainactivity then delete the data from sqlite and update reyclerview. How can I achieve this?

**MainActivity**

```
public class SelectedProblems extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selecte_problem_drawal);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_recycle_view); // Instantiate Recyclerview
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    selectedProblemsAdapter = new SelectedProblemsAdapter(this, getAllItems(),  listener);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(selectedProblemsAdapter);

   Button remove = findviewbyid(R.id.remove);
   remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   }
  }
```

**SelectedProblemsAdapter**

```
  public SelectedProblemsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, OnItemClick listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        listener = listener;

    }

    @Override
    public SelectedProblemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_selected_problems_content, null, false);
        return new SelectedProblemsViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SelectedProblemsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (this.cursor != null){
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != cursor ? cursor.getCount(): 0);
    }

    public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class SelectedProblemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView selectedProblems, selectedProblemPrice, selectedProblemTotal;
        Button remove_problem_from_cart;
        public SelectedProblemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            selectedProblems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problems);
            selectedProblemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_price);
            selectedProblemTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectedProblemTotal);
            remove_problem_from_cart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_problem_from_cart);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**MainActivity**

```
public class SelectedProblems extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selecte_problem_drawal);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_recycle_view); // Instantiate Recyclerview
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    selectedProblemsAdapter = new SelectedProblemsAdapter(this, getAllItems(),  listener);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(selectedProblemsAdapter);

   Button remove = findviewbyid(R.id.remove);
   remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   }
  }
```

**SelectedProblemsAdapter**

```
 public SelectedProblemsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, OnItemClick listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        listener = listener;

    }

    @Override
    public SelectedProblemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_selected_problems_content, null, false);
        return new SelectedProblemsViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SelectedProblemsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (this.cursor != null){
           // it will call your interface method which is implemented in Activity
           holder.yourView_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           listener.yourmethod();
   }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != cursor ? cursor.getCount(): 0);
    }

    public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class SelectedProblemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView selectedProblems, selectedProblemPrice, selectedProblemTotal;
        Button remove_problem_from_cart;
        public SelectedProblemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            selectedProblems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problems);
            selectedProblemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_price);
            selectedProblemTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectedProblemTotal);
            remove_problem_from_cart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_problem_from_cart);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by implementing an interface.

Step 1: Create an interface with an abstract function that takes in the type of data as its parameters.

```
public interface OnDataItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(YourItem yourItem);

    }
```

Step 2: Make the activity implement the interface and override its methods.

```
public class SelectedProblems extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selecte_problem_drawal);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_recycle_view); // 
    //Instantiate Recyclerview
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    selectedProblemsAdapter = new SelectedProblemsAdapter(this, getAllItems());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(selectedProblemsAdapter);

  
  }

  @Override
    public void onItemClick(YourItem yourItem) {


}
```

Step 3: Pass the interface through the adapter's constructor.

```
//Global variable of the interface 
private onDataItemClickListener  onclickListner;

// while instatiating the adapter
 selectedProblemsAdapter = new SelectedProblemsAdapter(this, getAllItems(), onClickListener);
```

Step 4: In the onBindViewHolder method, use the interface instance(received through the constructor) to call the methods, which will help pass the data to the main activity/ activity.

```
     public SelectedProblemsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, OnDataItemClickListener listener) {
            this.context = context;
            this.cursor = cursor;
            listener = listener;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public SelectedProblemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_selected_problems_content, null, false);
            return new SelectedProblemsViewHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SelectedProblemsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (this.cursor != null){
              holder.yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    // onItemClick is the abstract function present in the interface.
               listener.onItemClicked(" your data item ");

    // here the data item/position etc, which you want to delete will be passed on to the main acticity.
       }
            }
        }

       @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (null != cursor ? cursor.getCount(): 0);
        }
    
        public void update(Cursor cursor) {
            this.cursor = cursor;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    
        class SelectedProblemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    
            TextView selectedProblems, selectedProblemPrice, selectedProblemTotal;
            Button remove_problem_from_cart;
            public SelectedProblemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                selectedProblems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problems);
                selectedProblemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_price);
                selectedProblemTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectedProblemTotal);
                remove_problem_from_cart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_problem_from_cart);
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Step 5: Finally write the code to delete the object through the overridden interface method, in the main activity.

```
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(YourItem yourItem) {
    
    yourItem.delete();
    // you can use any number of functions to perform with your dataItem here.
 
selectedProblemsAdapter.update()
//call your update function here to change the list in recycler view.

    }
```

Note: If you are using a view model and live data, you do not need to write the notifyDataSetChanged() function.The data gets updated automatically.

This will help you to delete or perform any number of operations on your data, which is passed from your adapter to the main activity.